# How to get between Records from lookup when we are passing range:

Tags: sql, ssis

I am getting range from Source like below 
Source Table::

```
ID  Begin   End

A1  12  25

B1  16  40
```

Lookup Table::

```
LID Name

14  aa

17  bb

28  cc
```

When applying lookup I need following::

```
ID  LID Name

A1  14  aa

A1  17  bb

B1  17  bb
```

B1  28  cc

Is there any way to get from Lookup Transformation, By passing some parameters

Here parameters are Begin and End.

Query looks like

SELECT LID, Name FROM LOOKUP_TABLE  WHERE LID BETWEEN ? AND ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your lookup transformation as follows:

1. On the 'General' tab, choose `Partial cache` as Cache mode.
2. On the 'Connections' tab, configure the connection to your lookup table.
3. On the 'Advanced' tab, check `Modify the SQL statement` and enter your parameterized query (see image 1).
4. Under the 'Modify SQL statement' box, click on the `Parameters` button to choose which columns you wish to use as parameters (see image 2).

[image: Modify the SQL statement]
[image: Choose parameters]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I already try this one. here it is returning first match between that Range. But how to get all records in that range.

Comment: The lookup transformation only return the first match by design. Consider performing this query at database level.